# Search first name and last name using AJAX

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a search input field that allows users to search matching records in AspNetUsers table. However, it displays the first name and last name but when I click the suggestion div, it does not take me to the matching one. Here is my code for the AspNetUser controller.

```
        public IActionResult Index(string searchString, int? page)
        {
            var pageNumber = page ?? 1;
            var users = from e in _context.AspNetUsers select e;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                users = users.Where(s => s.LastName.Contains(searchString) || s.FirstName.Contains(searchString));
            }

            return View(users.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 10));
        }

        //for the query 
        public string IndexAJAX(string searchString)
        {
            // Search employee by lastname OR firstname
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM AspNetUsers WHERE FirstName LIKE @p0 OR LastName LIKE @p0";
            string wrapString = "%" + searchString + "%";

            // Execute the SQL query and retrieve the matching users
            List<AspNetUser> queryUsers = _context.AspNetUsers.FromSqlRaw(sql, wrapString).ToList();

            // Convert the query result to a JSON string
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(queryUsers);
            return json;
        }
```

This is my AJAX script

```
<!--AJAX-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    function XAjaxRequest(searchString) {
        if (searchString.length < 3) {
            //on deleting input to enter something else, needs clear
            document.getElementById("autoSuggestContainer").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        }
        var xmlhttp;
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        //url must be matching with the ControllerName/ActionMethod
        var url = "/ManageUser/IndexAJAX?searchString=" + searchString;
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, false);
        xmlhttp.send();
        //displays the suggested div
        document.getElementById("autoSuggestContainer").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("autoSuggestContainer").innerHTML = "";

        var messageObject = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText); // receive the respose text

        var autoSuggestions = "";

        for (var i = 0; i < messageObject.length; i++) {
            autoSuggestions +=
                // + messageObject[i].FirstName + "\" " + messageObject[i].LastName + "\" "

                "<input type=\"button\" value=\"" + messageObject[i].FirstName + " " + messageObject[i].LastName + "\" "
                //once suggested was clicked  --> it will change the input search to suggested string
                + "onclick=\"document.getElementById('searchString').value = this.value; document.getElementById('searchForm').submit();\" "
                + "style =\"width: 280px\" />";
            autoSuggestions += "<br />";
        }
        //place the generated buttons HTML code inside the display div
        document.getElementById("autoSuggestContainer").innerHTML = autoSuggestions;
    }
</script>
```

I want the auto-suggestion div to display both first name and last name and successfully take me to the matching record. When I only allow to search using first name, it works fine but when I try to add the last name, it would not display anything.